# Difference between "as_index = False", and "reset_index()" in pandas groupby

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I just wanted to know what is the difference in the function performed by these 2.

Data:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"ID":["A","B","A","C","A","A","C","B"], "value":[1,2,4,3,6,7,3,4]})
```

as_index=False :

```
df_group1 = df.groupby("ID").sum().reset_index()
```

reset_index() :

```
df_group2 = df.groupby("ID", as_index=False).sum()
```

Both of them give the exact same output.

```
  ID  value
0  A     18
1  B      6
2  C      6
```

Can anyone tell me what is the difference and any example illustrating the same?

Comment: They are exactly the same.

Comment: @QusaiAlothman: No, they're only the same in this particular case **because the OP's dataframe doesn't have an explicit index other than the default one 0,1,2...** so keeping it or resetting/dropping it doesn't make a difference. If the dataframe actually had an index e.g. 100, 101, 102.. the results would not be the same.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

When you use `as_index=False`, you indicate to `groupby()` that you don't want to set the column ID as the index (duh!). When both implementation yield the same results, use `as_index=False` because it will save you some typing and an unnecessary pandas operation ;)

However, sometimes, you want to apply more complicated operations on your groups. In those occasions, you might find out that one is more suited than the other.

***Example 1:*** You want to sum the values of three variables (i.e. columns) in a group on both axes.

Using `as_index=True` allows you to apply a sum over `axis=1` without specifying the names of the columns, then summing the value over axis 0. When the operation is finished, you can use `reset_index(drop=True/False)` to get the dataframe under the right form.

***Example 2:*** You need to set a value for the group based on the columns in the `groupby()`.

Setting `as_index=False` allow you to check the condition on a common column and not on an index, which is often way easier.

At some point, you might come across `KeyError` when applying operations on groups. In that case, it is often because you are trying to use a column in your aggregate function that is currently an index of your GroupBy object.